# Visual Studio Tools for good programming practices

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

As the title indicates, I want to know if there are any tools or plugins to add to Visual Studio in order to help programmers write efficient code (i.e : naming standards, variables initializing...)

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes resharper from www.jetbrains.com is good.
Visual Assist from www.wholetomato.com is good too.

Those are both paid tools.

Style cop would help you enforce coding standards.